Prevent references to default 'latest' module version
Our policy is that consumers of terraform modules must reference an explicit version id.
I want to block any possibility of a developer referencing a module without
?ref=vx.x.x

Or, if there is a way to make "latest" unavailable?
Is there a way to enforce that natively in terraform, or via AZDO?
I've seen suggestions that involve integrating 3rd party tools - but that's a heavy lift for what I thought would be a simple & common requirement.
Appreciate any insights...
Thanks

I am assuming you are using git sources here? If so then the short answer is no. Terraform its self isnt really doing the lifting here. Its just using the source for a git pull really. And git without a ref will just pull the latest from the default branch.

As a workaround, you can add some linter to your CI process that will check these versions.
